# What codes represent what genes?

Tags: rna-seq, database, unsupervised-learning

I want to run experiments on the data used in *PatternMarkers & GWCoGAPS for novel data-driven biomarkers via whole transcriptome NMF* [link](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/33/12/1892/2975325?login=false)

So far, the paper has  reduced the dimension to

- ammon's horn
- amygdala
- anterior cingulate cortex
- caudate nucleus
- dorsolateral prefrontal cortex
- first cervical spinal cord segment
- frontal cortex
- hypothalamus
- putamen
- substantia nigra

on the samples/patients GTEX-[11GSP, 11O72, 11OF3, 11TUW, Q2AG, QDT8, XAB4]

I assume they are using it.

```
Gene read count.    GTEx_Analysis_v6_RNA-seq_RNA-SeQCv1.1.8_gene_reads.gct.gz
```

A small amount of the data is

```
Name               Description  GTEX-111CU-1826-SM-5GZYN  GTEX-111FC-0226-SM-5N9B8  GTEX-111VG-2326-SM-5N9BK  ...
ENSG00000223972.4  DDX11L1      0                         0                         0                         ...
```

From what I can gather, `ENSG00000223972.4  DDX11L1`  is the `DEAD/H-box helicase 11 like 1`

Therefore, I assumed that looking for the term `first cervical spinal cord segment` would give me the name and description.

Therefore, I am wondering if I have the correct data set.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. ENSG00000223972 Is indeed a gene ID. But the terms you list are brain regions, not genes, presumably indicating the sample source